# how to await Stream multiple time in Dart?

Tags: dart, async-await, stream

How can I await a stream (or any other event queue) multiple times?

I tried `Stream.first` & `Stream.single`, both doesn't work.

What I want to do:

```dart
//next is a fake member
Future<void> xxx() async {
  final eventStream = foo();
  await eventStream.next; // wait for first event
  //do some work
  await eventStream.next; // wait for second event
  //do some other differnet work
  await eventStream.next; // wait for 3rd event
  // another differnet work
  return;
}
```

equvalent to:

```
Future<void> xxx() async {
  final eventStream = foo();
  int i=0;
  await for (final _ in eventStream){
     if(i==0);//do some work
     else if(i==1);//do some other differnet work
     else if(i==2){;break;}//another differnet work
     ++i;
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [StreamQueue](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html) from `package:async`.

```dart
var q = StreamQueue(eventStream);
var v1 = await q.next;
var v2 = await q.next;
var v3 = await q.next;
// other work.
await q.cancel(); // If not listened to completely yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up with a custom class

```dart
class CompleterQueue<T> {
  final _buf = <Completer<T>>[];
  var _iWrite = 0;
  var _iRead = 0;

  int get length => _buf.length;

  Future<T> next() {
    if (_iRead == _buf.length) {
      _buf.add(Completer<T>());
    }
    final fut = _buf[_iRead].future;
    _iRead += 1;
    _cleanup();
    return fut;
  }

  void add(T val) {
    if (_iWrite == _buf.length) {
      final prm = Completer<T>();
      _buf.add(prm);
    }
    _buf[_iWrite].complete(val);
    _iWrite += 1;
    _cleanup();
  }

  void _cleanup() {
    final minI = _iWrite < _iRead ? _iWrite : _iRead;
    if (minI > 0) {
      _buf.removeRange(0, minI);
      _iWrite -= minI;
      _iRead -= minI;
    }
  }
}
```